# Drupal Commerce assign role on account create on checkout

Tags: commerce

When a checkout is completed by an anonymous user on a Drupal Commerce website, a Drupal account will be created. I would look to auto-assign a role like 'customer' to the newly created Commerce user. How can I do that programmatically? It has to be in Drupal 7 code so I can use it for my custom module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$account = new stdClass;
$account->is_new = TRUE; //indicate the account is new
$account->name = 'account_name';
$account->pass = user_hash_password('password'); // make a function to create random passwords
$account->mail = 'email';
$account->init = 'email';
$account->status = TRUE; //set the user to activated at creation
$account->roles = array(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => TRUE); //set user as authenticated user
$account->timezone = variable_get('date_default_timezone', '');
$new_user = user_save($account); //create user (user_save() returns a fully loaded $user object)


$role_name = 'ROLE_NAME'; // The name of the role to add.
if ($role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name)) {
  user_multiple_role_edit(array($new_user->uid), 'add_role', $role->rid);
}
```

You can use the hook: hook_user_insert. 
And apply the last piece of code from above to update the role.

Comment: I think I have been unclear. Drupal Commerce already creates an account when the checkout is completed. Somehow I have to jump in, for example with a commerce hook and fetch the newly added user and edit the role there.

Comment: You can use the hook: hook_user_insert.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7

And apply the last piece of code from above to update the role.

Comment: Ah, yes. That sounds good. I'll let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: I made an error in my thinking: all new users should be assigned the customer role. So this was my final implementation: 

    hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
          if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {
            $user_roles = user_roles(TRUE);
            $default_role = avariable_get('debtor_settings_default_role');
            if (!isset($edit['roles'])) {
              $edit['roles'] = array();
            }
            $edit['roles'] = array($default_role => $user_roles[$default_role]);
          }
        }

Comment: @dimitril Consider adding what you report in your first comment in the answer itself. The answer should not be searched in the comments.